# Unable to login with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to use python to login into my website account. This code works for facebook, but don't know why doens't work with att.com. there's a pop up window during page redirect, not sure what's missing.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

class ATT_LOGIN(object):

    def __init__(self, login, password):
        """ Start up... """
        self.login = login
        self.password = password

        self.cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
        self.opener.addheaders = [
            ('User-agent', ('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; '
                           'Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'))
        ]

        # need this twice - once to set cookies, once to log in...
        self.loginToATT()
        print self.loginToATT()

    def loginToATT(self):
        """
        Handle login. This should populate our cookie jar.
        """
        login_data = urllib.urlencode({
            'userid' : self.login,
            'password' : self.password,
        })
        response = self.opener.open("https://www.att.com/olam/loginAction.doview", login_data)
        return ''.join(response.readlines())
```

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that these are the only form fields that the site needs, or even that it's the right page to send them to? If so… what reason? From a quick glance, I see a form with dozens of fields, whose target is some JS function… If you're just expecting this to work because Facebook works… not every login page is implemented the same way.

Comment: @abarnert the url i provide is from the doLogin JS function, which change form's action attribute, I assume that will be the target I post my username and password.

Comment: Use something like firebug or other web browser development tools to actually log in and see what data and to what url it was `POST`ed.